# Would hooking an AJAX function into a link work?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, hyperlink

I have a site where I have a lot of outgoing links and I would like to count the clicks to those outgoing links.

I need to keep the links need to be visible. (as in, no Digg like links or redirects).

So I was thinking of hooking some jQuery function to all outgoing links. This function then calls a PHP script via AJAX that updates the counter.

I have done similar things with form submitting. Where the form's onsubmit does a return of a JavaScript function. But does it work with onclick and links? Wondering about scenarios like when a person middle clicks in Firefox to get a new tab.

BTW I do not care about people with JavaScript off. They will just go to the link and not be counted, it's fine.

Comment: Why don't you want the redirect? Even google does it.

Comment: I want the user to see the url in the status bar. And Daniel came with a cool answer for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this isn't directly answering your question, but you might want to rethink redirects (if done the Google way).  Taken from [someone else's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714966/capture-who-clicked-a-link-from-website-a-to-website-b/714988#714988):

> Google has found a sneaky way around
>   this problem by actually using
>   Javascript to change the link instead
>   of the status bar. When the page is
>   loaded, the links in the results list
>   go to their actual destinations, but
>   every link has an onmousedown
>   javascript event that changes the link
>   when you click on it. You can see this
>   in action by right-clicking on a link.
>   After you've done that, hovering over
>   the link will now show the true
>   destination (Google's click-tracking
>   script) in the status bar instead of
>   the result's real URL.

That way you could maintain visible links but also be able to monitor traffic via redirects.  (As I understand it, your only opposition to redirects are the accessibility of links - if there's more, then ignore this answer.)

Comment: Interesting stuff, i indeed do not want redirects due to the fact that people do not see the destination in the status bar.

Comment: BTW that rightclick thing did not work on my local google (google.is) but it does work on google.com

Answer (score 1):

You might need client-side javascript which can make an XMLHTTPRequest to a webservice or a page with parameters (e.g. unique client id)

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="registerClick(this.document.getElementById('uniqueId')); return true;">google</a>
```

Here register click could be a function that can make a request to a server-side page, which can become the click register.